# How to do a Subqueries join with TypeORM QueryBuilder (relation of a relation of a relation)

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I want to transform the below SQL query (tested & working), into a TypeORM query with QueryBuilder, but I can't figure out how (keep getting error that user_roles_role is not joined):

```
select "invite"."code", "invite"."expired", "invite"."sent", "role"."name" as "user_role"
    from "invite"
    left join "user_roles_role"
      on "user_roles_role"."user_id"="invite"."user_id"
    left join "role"
      on "role"."_id"="user_roles_role"."role_id"
    where "invite"."code"=$1
    and "role"."name"='ADMIN';
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure it out thanks to this article: https://dev.to/yoshi_yoshi/typeorm-query-builder-with-subquery-490c

Here is the equivalent QueryBuilder code to my SQL code:

```
const invites = await this.connection
    .getRepository(Invite)
    .createQueryBuilder('invite')
    .select(['invite.code', 'invite.sent', 'invite.expired', 'role.name'])
    .leftJoinAndSelect('invite.user', 'user')
    .leftJoinAndSelect('user.roles', 'role')
    .where('invite.code = :id', { id: code })
    .andWhere('role.name = :name', { name: 'ADMIN' })
    .getOne()
```